# How to solve strange behavior of self-created styles with bullets

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, list, bullets

Everyone who uses bullets in Word knows, when you hit enter after an empty bullet (so no text after the bullet), when using `List Paragraph` style, the bullet disappears and the active style will become the `Normal` style.

However, try the following:

- Start a bulleted list
- Create a new style and call it, for example, `New List Paragraph`
- Hit enter.

You will see that, as you would expect, the bullet disappears. However, the active style remains `New List Paragraph` and the indentation is incorrect. The active style doesn't switch to `Normal`. You have to select the `Normal` style manually to fix this.

Of course, this is not what you want. Especially when you are creating a nice template for everyone in the office to use.

Hope someone has a fix for this bug or a nice solution/elegant workaround.

Comment: When you create your style if you set "Style for following paragraph" to Normal, you will get the desired result.

Comment: @Tanya: This solves one problem, but creates another (I had already tried this). The problem is that if you do this and you do want to continue a bulleted list, you run into problems. This way, the bulleted list will exit each time you press enter, also when you don't wat to exit the list. So you need to switch back to the New List Paragraph for each bullet.

Comment: The trick to working around that is that if you have a space character at end of paragraph before you press Enter, the bullet style will carry over to the next paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Word's built-in List Paragraph style will automatically convert the last empty paragraph of a list to a Normal style paragraph when the Return key is pressed. Word includes special programming to do this and user defined list styles do not get this functionality.

There is no elegant workaround for this... the user must be trained to apply a different style. One thing that can help train the user is to include the StyleGalleryClassic function on the QAT. Get it from the Popular Commands list. With this visible the user will always see contextually the style name for the active selection point.